# Элемент перерисовывается только после onResume()

Tags: android

Есть код,
я выбрал цвет, сохранил его List colors;
дальше я говорю пяти элементам взять последние пять цветов и применить его пяти элементам на экране. То есть элементы должны перерисоваться, но по факту они перерисовываются только после onResume. Как сделать моментальные изменения?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы перерисовать элементы, попробуйте использовать метод [invalidate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()).

Comment: Спасибо тебе Рамил, все заработало.